# MySQL Auto Increment?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have 2 different MySQL servers.
One is 5.6.12 the other 5.5.25a.

In the 5.5 version server I can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
ALTER TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 50;
```

The 5.6 version only allows me to change the auto_increment to a higher value than auto_increment is in that moment.

Of course I'm not trying to change the value to a lower value than the record that has the maximum value.

Both MySQL servers are InnoDB

I need to use that commen in the newest version

Any clue?

Comment: Double check if there are no values higher or equal to 50 in that column. There were no changes in how MySQL treats AUTO_INCREMENT column between 5.5 and 5.6.

Answer (score 2):

This query works in both mysql 5.6.12 and 5.5.25:

```
ALTER TABLE  `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT =10
```

According to [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html):

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal
>   to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value
>   is reset to the current maximum plus one. **For InnoDB, if the value is
>   less than the current maximum value in the column, no error occurs and
>   the current sequence value is not changed.**

If the table has no records, you can use `TRUNCATE`:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name
```

From [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/truncate-table.html):

> Any AUTO_INCREMENT value is reset to its start value. This is true
>   even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence
>   values.

---

UPDATE: It looks like there is some bug with mysql5.6.12: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69882

Comment: Thats correct, it's what I'm using.

For example, with an empty table, I do: ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;

It sets the Auto increment to 100, and this works perfect.

The problem is if I want to change to a lower value, with the table still empty ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;

It doesn't work at all.

This is the problem I have.

Comment: Yes, but the value I'm trying to set is lower than the current auto increment value and higher than the current maximun value in the column...and it's not working. And this is new because in the old version of MySQL it works...¿?

Comment: Yes, but I can't truncate when there are FK in the table. I could do some tricks, like SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0, but what IU want to know is why is not working anymore...

Comment: Thanks I see the bug, I hope they will fix it.